# Highlight row when two columns contain specified values

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I have 2 columns "N" and "O" .  Both columns can contain "x".  If column N has an x and column O is null then highlight the line. This should apply to the entire worksheet.  Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: So you logic is: IF( N contains "x" AND column N+1 = null) Then highlight the entire line?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know of to do this would be by using a filter to hide the rows you don't want to highlight.

1. Begin by highlighting your desired data, including the header row.
2. Press the **Sort & Filter** button and select **Filter**.  This will
   put little dropdown arrows on all the row headers.
3. Click the dropdown for column N and alter the checkboxes so only `X`
   is checked.  This will filter all the rows so it hides anything
   without an X in column N.
4. Next, click the dropdown for column N and uncheck everything except
   the `(Blanks)` option.  This will hide any rows that are not blank in
   column N.
5. The resulting visible rows are the ones you want highlighted. 
   Simply select them all and apply the your desired highlighting.
6. To show all lines again, click the **Sort & Filter** button and
   uncheck the **Filter** option.

Answer (score 0):

To have the highlighting change along with any data changes, you could use conditional formatting with a rule such as

`=AND($N1="x",ISBLANK($O1))` applied to `=$1:$17`

(17 here is the assumed total number of relevant rows).

[image: SU515355 example]